# Simple, server-side ASP.NET richtext control?

Tags: asp.net

I'm aware of TinyMce, FCKeditor, and Telerik RadEditor, but they are all too heavy weight for my needs. I just want a text box where the user can mark text as bold, italic, make a list, and most importantly spellcheck it. It should also be able to count the number of characters entered. Where I'm at now is a custom server control built on TinyMce, but this seems like such overkill and the delay while it converts the text areas client side is not very slick.

Is there a smaller, more lightweight rich text editor out there?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

```
<FTB:FreeTextBox ID="textBoxBody" ToolbarLayout="Bold,Italic,Underline,JustifyLeft,JustifyRight,JustifyCenter,JustifyFull" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="500px" EnableHtmlMode="False"></FTB:FreeTextBox>
```

go for download here: [FreeTextBox](http://freetextbox.com/download/)

Answer (score 0):

I've used [RTE](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/item.aspx?i=498) in the past. 
It is free, server side and lightweight.
This doesn't spell check or count characters though.